# VBA Macro Execution Order

Tags: vba, excel

I am running the following Macro on an excel workbook I have

```
Public Sub Iterate()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 1
    With Worksheets("Iterations")


    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AB6:AB16","AS8").Copy
    .Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

What is plugged randomized in the AB column, is then invoking a calculation on all columns from "AG:AT"

now when I run the macro, random numbers are generated, and after they are generated --- I want the macro to copy the output from AB and AS to another sheet "Iterations" which it does.

**Edit 2**

The problem is that I need only "AB6:AB16" and "AS8" to be copied in the same instance, and not split it to two lines of code.

When I run the macro now, it copies all the columns to "AS8", instead of copying "AB6:AB16" and just the cell "AS8"

Comment: Instead of explaining with words, give a concrete (simplified) example of data in a few cells, just enough to reproduce the problem. Also provide (in text) the desired output, and how it differs from what you get for that sample data.

Comment: so, what is preventing you from adding code that copies data fro AB and AS to sheet "Iteration" ?   ...  by the way, please do not use the "With" command. in your case it simplified two lines and made intent of the code less obvious at first glance.  ... if you really need to use it then use _With Worksheets("Calculator")_ ... it will simplify three lines

Comment: @jsotola, there is no problem, it copies it, however, it doesn't copy the data accurate.
Meaning, it copies the data, and when I try to validate it, the data that is copied from Column "AS" is not right..

Comment: You say that the data in AS is based on random numbers, so are you sure that the data in column AS hasn't been recalculated between when it was copied and when you "validate" it?

Comment: The data in AS is based on data coming form AB, I validate it by looking at the values and plugging it to the same excel sheet, without the random numbers function on another computer

Comment: ok. please do this test ... go to an empty cell in column AD, for example. somewhere near your data in AB. input anything into that cell ... anything at all, as long as there is a change in the worksheet. this should trigger a recalculation. watch the data in AB and in AS when you do this.  did any of the cells change when you did that ???

Comment: @jsotola yes, there was a change in all cells. Which triggered a "refresh" basically

Comment: so, that is your problem then, as @YowE3K mentioned earlier, your data is changing between copy and validation, because the copy function triggers a recalculation

Comment: @jsotola That may not have been a valid test - the OP said that their validation was done by plugging the data into the same sheet **on another computer**.

Comment: @jsotola Forget I said that - I'm being an idiot.  The OP obviously has calculation on and therefore their copy is changing their random numbers.  Duh!  No, wait, they are only doing the one copy - that shouldn't matter.  (I think I will go find some coffee and think about this again when I have woken up :D)

Comment: Alright, I am semi-awake now, and I now see that the question has changed between when I first looked at it and now.  Now the copy will have the correct values, but just not copied into a "useful" location.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! It all helped a lot! 
And I managed to run my desired calculations thanks to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to get around your issue:

1. Switch off automatic calculation while you are doing the two copies (the input data and the output data), so that the copying of the input data won't trigger a change to the input data which leads to a change to the output data prior to it being copied, or
2. Store both the input data and the output data in memory while the two copies are done.

As #2 is my preferred way to go, I will show you some code that does that:

```
Public Sub Iterate()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim inputValues As Variant
    Dim outputValue As Variant

    For i = 1 To 1000
        With Worksheets("Iterations")
            inputValues = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AB6:AB16").Value
            outputValue = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AS8").Value
            .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(11, i)).Value = inputValues
            .Cells(12, i).Value = outputValue
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```